# Не отображаются данные из базы в шаблоне

Tags: php, html

Всем привет!

После переноса сайта с локалки на хостинг (reg.ru) перестали отображаться данные, загружаемые из дб. На локалке они работают. Тех. поддержка ничем не смогла помочь.

Версия PHP 7.1

Данные загружаются через контроллер, который берет информацию из базы с помощью модели

Контроллер Index.php

```
public function indexAction()
{
   $http = self::getHttp();
            return View::render('site/index',['slides'=>newsTemplate::getAll(0), 'blogs'=>blogTemplate::getIndexBlog()]);
}
```

Шаблон index.phtml

```
<?php if($slides !== null): ?>
                                    <?php foreach ($slides as $slide): ?>

                                        <div class="slidedItem firstItem" data-thumb="<?=$slide['imagelink']?>">
                                            <div class="btSliderPort wBackground cover" style="background-image: url('<?=$slide['imagelink']?>')">
                                                <div class="btSliderCell" data-slick="yes">
                                                    <div class="btSlideGutter">
                                                        <div class="btSlidePane">
                                                            <div class="btClear btSeparator topSemiSpaced noBorder">
                                                                <hr>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <header class="header btClear huge btDash topDash  btAccentDash btRegularTitle">
                                                                <p class="btSuperTitle"><?=$slide['title']?></p>
                                                                <div class="dash">
                                                                    <h1><span class="headline"><?=$slide['message']?></span></h1></div>
                                                            </header>
                                                            <div class="btClear btSeparator topExtraSmallSpaced noBorder">
                                                                <hr>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="bpgPhoto btTextCenter">
                                                                <div class="btImage"><img src="/public/img/truck-vignette-white.png" alt="/public/img/truck-vignette-white.png"></div>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="btClear btSeparator noBorder">
                                                                <hr>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="btIconImageRow">
                                                                <div class="btIco colorless borderless large"><span data-ico-cs="&#xe600;" class="btIcoHolder"></span></div>
                                                                <div class="btIco colorless borderless large"><span data-ico-cs="&#xe651;" class="btIcoHolder"></span></div>
                                                                <div class="btIco colorless borderless large"><span data-ico-cs="&#xe65d;" class="btIcoHolder"></span></div>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="btClear btSeparator topSemiSpaced noBorder">
                                                                <hr>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>


                                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
```

Прежде чем обратиться к контроллеру, данные проходят через файл bootstrap.php

```
    <?php
require_once ROOT . 'init/Autoload.php';
error_reporting (0);
use \library\Route,
    \library\DB,
    \library\View,
    \library\FileCache,
    \library\Application;

Autoload::register(ROOT);
DB::__init();
FileCache::__init();
View::__Init();

if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.6.0') < 0) {
    die('[My PHP version(' . PHP_VERSION . ')] << [APP PHP version(5.3.0)]');
}

$route = new Route(true);

Application::__Init();

// Главная
$route->get('/', function () {
    return Application::getPage('index::index');
});

$route->Render();
```

Основной index файл

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Moscow');

define('ROOT', realpath(__DIR__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

define('DISPLAY_ERROR', true);

if (DISPLAY_ERROR === true) {
    if (!ini_get('display_errors')) {
        ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    }
    error_reporting(E_ALL | E_NOTICE | E_STRICT);
} else {
    ini_set('display_errors', 0);
    error_reporting(0);
}

require_once ROOT . 'init/bootstrap.php';
```

Поддержка написала следующее:

stat("/var/www/USER/data/www/site.ru/init/vendor/App/Model/newsTemplate.php", 0x7ffe8a2df860) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/var/www/USER/data/www/site.ru/init/vendor/App/Controller/Index.php", 0x7ffe8a2df910) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Но по этим адресам у меня файлов нет, кроме одного, который выполняет операции с базой данных.

Знатоки, подскажите, как решить эту проблему?

Comment: если вдруг с базой данных операции выполняются с помощью функций `mysql_*` то в пхп 7 они отсутствуют

Comment: изменил версию пхп на 5,6, толку нет (

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решён, проблема была в названии модели, оказалось, код чувствителен у регистру